# I filtered the Excel sheet with C#, modify it to select and filter multiple values at a time

Tags: c#

Multiple filters in Excel sheet using C#

Please refer to the below code

```
namespace FilterCode
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static Workbook filterWrkSheetDataSC(Workbook wrkBook, string sheet, string columnToFilter, string value)
        {
            Workbook filterdWB = wrkBook;
            List<Range> filteredRange = null;
            if (filterdWB == null) throw new ArgumentException("Parameter : Workbook to be filter is null");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnToFilter) | string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(columnToFilter)) throw new ArgumentException("Parameter : columnToFilter is null or empty");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) | string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) throw new ArgumentException("Parameter : value is null or empty");

            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sheet) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sheet)))
            {
                Worksheet wrkSheet = (Worksheet)filterdWB.Worksheets[sheet];
                wrkSheet.Activate();
                wrkSheet.AutoFilterMode = false;
                Range range = wrkSheet.UsedRange;
                range.EntireColumn.Hidden = false;
                range.EntireRow.Hidden = false;

                int columnNumber = ColumnLetterToColumnIndex(columnToFilter);
                range.AutoFilter(columnNumber, value);
                filterdWB.Save();          

            }
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Parameter : sheet is null or empty");


            return filterdWB;
        }        

        private static int ColumnLetterToColumnIndex(string columnLetter)
        {
            columnLetter = columnLetter.ToUpper();
            int sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < columnLetter.Length; i++)
            {
                sum *= 26;
                sum += (columnLetter[i] - 'A' + 1);
            }
            return sum;
        }      

    }
}
```

Its only filtering one value and the requirement is to filter multiple.

Comment: which library are you using and the sample XML data also share the value of columnToFilter.

Comment: I am passing column address e.g. "A", "B", "C" in columnToFilter  and its a c# workflow application and using a private built library

Comment: what do you mean by 1filtering one value and the requisite is to filter multiple` multiple What? Column or Value?

Comment: if you want to filter multiple columns you should share about the range.AutoFilter method implementation.

Comment: To be specific, I want to filter multiple values from one column